# Looking for a regex to extract some values from a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this: `MemRegions: 202004 total, 7637M resident, 46M private, 1936M shared.`. I want to use a regex to get the value for `private` and `shared`. Below is my regex but it doesn't work: `/((.*\s)(private|shared))+/`. I need the regex to return the value `46M` and `1936M`. How can I create such regex? I know string.split works but I think regex would make the code shorter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const string = 'MemRegions: 202004 total, 7637M resident, 46M private, 1936M shared.';
const matchs = /.*resident,\s{1}(.*)\s{1}private,\s{1}(.*)\s{1}shared/.exec(string);

console.log(matchs[1], matchs[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your string will always contain private and shared segments

`/.*,\s(\d*\w)\sprivate,\s(\d*\w)\sshared/` group 1 and group 2 will give you expected values

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
/(([0-9M]+)\s+(private|shared))+/
```

Add letters other than M if you need them.

Comment: this one doesn't seem to work. It returns only private value.

Comment: It finds shared too, you just have to add a 'g' on the end, and exec multiple times.